# Windows 10 Global Shortcut

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, hotkeys

Guys I have a problem that is grinding my gears for a couple of days. First of all I'm using *Windows 10 Insider Preview build 14295.rs1_release.106318-1628*. After updated to that version (I don't know if really was there) I'm not be able to press CTRL+N, CTRL+P and CTRL+O on **ANY** windows application after some minutes computer starts. I mean, I can use those hotkeys a few minutes after windows starts, later that I cannot open new window on Google Chrome nor create a new file on Sublime Text 3 which are the commands for CTRL+N. I use this notebook for work since the last year and those hotkeys uses to work on Windows 8.1 and after upgrading to Windows 10.

I've tried [Ethervane ActiveHotkeys](http://www.tranglos.com/activehotkeys/), Hotkey Commander and Hotkey Explorer, [Shortcut Key Explorer](http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/shortcutkeys/download.shtml) and a couple of other programs and I only discovered that something is binding those keys, but I couldn't find who was. I'm sure that is not a Start Menu Shortcut because it disallow to set hotkeys like CTRL+[A-Z].

I'm considering that all this mess is a work of a module (.dll) which is creating a binding, however System Explorer doesn't shows necessary information to me. I wish you would give me a path to walk through because I've tried all that I could.

Comment: Boot into safe mode.

Comment: So I have to boot into safe mode for ever?

Comment: I assume by that comment the shortcut worked while in Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes, using safe mode I could use the hotkeys for a long time. Back to normal mode, I tried to see on System Explorer which program is messing up, but it's hard to identify on 'naked eyes'.

Comment: Use Autoruns using a process of elimination to determine that program that causes the shortcut to cease to function.  In other words don't automaticaly start any application, then one by one, add each application that normally starts.

Comment: I removed all programs from Run and RunOnce, either with "Startup Delayer" and the issue continues. On early startup I'm be able to use those hotkeys, after about 3 to 5 minutes suddendly it stops to work. I was wondering if was a Windows service doing that, but how identify though?

Comment: Repeat the process with the services, only enable those, required to start your machine.  You indicated Safe Mode works, so you know there is a configuration you can manually implement, that prevents this problem from happening.  Until you do that you cannot determine the cause of this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try to disable some services and keep you updated if I can resolve or not that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from OP (originally posted as an update to the question):

> I finally solved the issue. It was the "Dell Product Registration" which was binding those hotkeys. I realised that using "Process Hacker", showing the column "Start time", sorting desc and starting with Windows. When the OS started, I opened my Sublime Text and pressed a hotkey until it stopped work. So I found a bunch of applications candidates to kill and after stop the mouse over Process Hacker on tray, I saw that `prodreg.exe` was consuming 0.8% of CPU. I closed it and voilá, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> is working fine now.

Comment: Huge thanks for this one! I can't really tell what triggered it off, but it started happening lately on my machine. Your findings hit the nail right on the head. I'd like to add that I had NirSoft's HotKeysList running in the background and as soon as I killed `prodreg.exe`, beyond killing the hotkeys you specified, it also killed  [CTRL]+[+] and [CTRL]+[-]